# PHP MySQL : Unable to Connect to Database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am trying to connect to database in php , Database name is `photo_gallery` following is my code

**Database.php**

```
    define("DB_SERVER", "localhost"); 
    define("SERVER_NAME", "root"); 
    define("DB_PASS" ,"");
    define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");

    class MySQLDatabase{

        function __construct(){
            $this->open_connection();
        }

        private $connection ; 
        public function open_connection (){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_NAME, DB_PASS);
            if(!$this->connection){
                die("Connection failed".mysqli_error());
        }
        else {
            $db_select=  mysqli_select_db($this->connection,DB_NAME);
            if(!$db_select){
                echo 'Database selection failed '.mysqli_error($this->connection);
            }
        }
    }
        public  function query($sql){
            $query = mysqli_query($this->connection,$sql); 
            $this->confirm_query($query);
            return $query;
        }       

        private function confirm_query($result_set){
            $query= mysqli_query($this->connection,$result_set); 
            if(!$query){
                    die('Database query failed '.mysqli_error());
            } 
        }

        public function close_connection(){
            if(isset($this->connection)){
                mysqli_close($this->connection);
                unset($this->connection);
            }
        }       
    }
```

now when i run i get following error

> Database selection failed Access denied for user: ' @' @ localhost ' .
>   Base ' photo_gallery

i have confirmed username / password and db  details but still unable to resolve . Please guide me about it

Comment: Look at the HTML page source with this error. I suspect you're missing some information, like `<>` characters in there.  In any case, it is clear that it's an access issue. The username connecting doesn't have access. But your username should not look like `user@localhost` as implied by the `@` there in the error. It should just be `user`

Comment: `mysqli_connect` is missing an argument

Comment: Also, it apparently looks like you are using `DB_NAME` which might be the _database name_ rather than the username.  Isn't `SERVER_NAME` (root) your user here?

Comment: @dagon db name is optional. `mysqli_select_db()` is called later

Comment: i mis-typed not missing, just the wrong one

Comment: Are you writing your own ORM? That's probably not a good idea. Modern PHP development encourages the use of a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)  that gives you a solid foundation for building your application. Find one that suits your style and needs and follow the examples and documentation. Most have a large library of community code you can add in with little effort, avoiding the need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @tadman  i am learning how to develope oop based simple cms  from scratch ..

Comment: That's am ambitious undertaking. You might want to build it on top of a framework or you'll have one heck of a time getting it feature complete. Writing PHP from the ground up is extremely time consuming and unless you've worked with several frameworks before and know them inside and out, you'll probably spend a lot of time painfully repeating the mistakes of others. Your code here prevents people from using the placeholder feature, for example, rendering your code vulnerable to severe SQL injection bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied a username - your `mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_NAME, DB_PASS)` line doesn't define a user, so you're trying to connect to your database with *no* user.

Try `mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, SERVER_NAME, DB_NAME, DB_PASS)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

second parameter of the connect method of mysqli-connect is the USERNAME .
use it like this

$this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASS, DB_NAME );

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you chose bad names for your constants..

*SERVER_NAME* is not a good name for the database username..

As a consecuence of this, you used it wrong.. I suggest to change the constant to *DB_USER* and use it properly in the mysqli_connect() function..

**Remember to use names that really represent what they do/refer..**

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax:

```
   $conn= mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mydb");
```

Here is the code:

**Database.php**

```
    define("DB_SERVER", "localhost"); 
    define("SERVER_NAME", "root"); 
    define("DB_PASS" ,"");
    define("DB_NAME", "photo_gallery");

    class MySQLDatabase{

        function __construct(){
            $this->open_connection();
        }

        private $connection ; 
        public function open_connection (){
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, SERVER_NAME, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
            if(!$this->connection){
                die("Connection failed".mysqli_error());
        }
        else {
            $db_select=  mysqli_select_db($this->connection,DB_NAME);
            if(!$db_select){
                echo 'Database selection failed '.mysqli_error($this->connection);
            }
        }
    }
        public  function query($sql){
            $query = mysqli_query($this->connection,$sql); 
            $this->confirm_query($query);
            return $query;
        }       

        private function confirm_query($result_set){
            $query= mysqli_query($this->connection,$result_set); 
            if(!$query){
                    die('Database query failed '.mysqli_error());
            } 
        }

        public function close_connection(){
            if(isset($this->connection)){
                mysqli_close($this->connection);
                unset($this->connection);
            }
        }       
    }
```